# PrimeFaces 3.0 - How can I set a TreeNode icon programmatically from backing bean?

Tags: java, treeview, jsf-2, primefaces, treenode

I am trying to create a treeview using the PrimeFaces `<p:tree>` component. I copied the sample code from the PrimeFaces 3.0 Showcase and I have a simple treeview displaying very simple static content that is declared programmatically on the backing bean.

One of the showcase examples shows how you can assign icons (the JQueryUI type) to a `<p:treeNode>` in the Facelet code. That's nice eye-candy for the showcase, but how can I assign the icon via the associated `TreeNode` in the backing bean code? I don't see any getter/setter/method listed in the Javadocs.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm using the PrimeFaces 3.0-M2-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use EL in the `icon` attribute.

E.g.

```xml
<p:treeNode icon="#{item.icon}">
```

or, more generic (the `#{item.type}` can return e.g. `document`, `image`, etc)

```xml
<p:treeNode icon="ui-icon ui-icon-#{item.type}">
```