# PrimeFaces 5.3.5 - treeNode custom icons are invisible instead of it. There is ^

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, icons

```
<p:tree value="#{userFiltersBean.objectsTreeModel}" var="node" hideRootNode="true" styleClass="filtersTree">    
    <p:treeNode icon="#{node.leafIcon}" styleClass="myIconsSize">
```

It works but I do not see my custom icons. I see only ^. See this screenshot.
[^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGd8G.png)
[PrimeFaces 3.0 - How can I set a TreeNode icon programmatically from backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347161/primefaces-3-0-how-can-i-set-a-treenode-icon-programmatically-from-backing-bea)

1st approach
This is not working

```
.ui-menu .ui-icon {
  top: .2em;
  left: .2em;
}
```

2nd approach
I reduced size of icon and nothing happened. I see also only ^.

```
.myIconsSize {
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
}
```

3rd approach works well but it puts only last icon of tree component var (var="node") to each nodeTree. See my screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F7SP.png)

```
.ui-treenode .ui-treenode-content .ui-treenode-icon{
    background: url("#{node.leafIcon}") no-repeat top !important;
}
```

And there is my generated HTML output.

```
<span class="ui-tree-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
<span class="ui-treenode-icon ui-icon /images/tree-icons/18a6803865043ax59011635600000a0a0a0.png"></span>
<span class="ui-treenode-label ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="treeitem">Property</span>
```

I am not sure if it is important but I have FONT_AWESOME enabled in web.xml.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I use only this one. Did you mean it, please?
<context-param>
 <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
 <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

Comment: I am sorry @Skyware. My comments were absolutely off topic.

Comment: did you use the UI-Icon to see if it's working

Comment: @YagamiLight This works pretty good <p:treeNode icon="fa fa-bed"> but I need to use my custom icons from DB.

Comment: the mark that you found "^" mean that the icon was not accepted or the path is wrong and with my experience i know that TreeNode doesn't accept personal path with your own icon i hope that helped you

Comment: @YagamiLight Thanks, sounds relevant. I am trying to add my image path to CSS class of treeNode now.

Comment: If i can give my own opinion , i will work with UI-Icon it's offer a large choose of icon but it's my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem as @YagamiLight mentioned that

"the mark that you found "^" mean that the icon was not accepted or the path is wrong and with my experience i know that TreeNode doesn't accept personal path with your own icon i hope that helped you "

I solved it by 3rd approach.